# Prove that $A = \{(x,y) : x< y\}$ is an open set

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What I did:

Let$\ (a,b)$ be an arbitrary point of A then$\ a<b$, if$\ r=b-a$ and if we consider$\ (x,y)$ such that$\ (x,y)\in B_r(a,b)$ then we need to prove that$\ B_r(a,b)\subseteq A$ to show that$\ A$ is an open set.

Note that:

$\ |x-a| < \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} < r$ and $\ |y-b| < \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} < r$ therefore $\ |x-a|<r$ and $\ |y-b|<r$ so

$\ x<b$ and $\ a<y$ so $\ (x,y)\in B_r(a,b)\subseteq A $

Since$\ (x,y)\in B_r(a,b)$ then$\ (x,y)\subseteq A$ and we conclude that $\ B_r(a,b)\subseteq A$

Since $\ (a,b)$ was an arbitrary point, A is an open set

Why is this wrong?

Comment: Did you try to show $x <y$ with your chosen $(x,y) \in B_r(a,b)$?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: See my edit. $$

Comment: Well, yes, at least I think so...

Comment: No you didn't. If you attempted to do so, you will see your choice of r is problematic. Take (a,b)=(0,1). Now r =1 and the point (.64, .45) is in the circle.

Comment: Let $a = 0, b = 1$.  Then the point $(.5, .5)$ is at a distance of $1/\sqrt{2} < 1 = b-a = r$ from $(a,b)$ but $(.5, .5)$ is not in $A$.

Comment: Ah, beaten to the punch.  @DavidTomahak Try drawing a picture of the set $A$, and a point $a,b$ with a circle about it of radius $b-a$, and you will see the problem.

Comment: Try computing the distance from $(a,b)$ to the line $y=x$, and make sure $r$ is at least that small.

Comment: What?  I don't understand why you think your proof has shown anything.  You have |x-a|<r and you conclude x < b.  Why?  And a < y. Why? And then (x,y) in A.  Why?  I can't make any sense out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove this using the the fact that that $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is open if and only if $\bar{S} = \mathbb{R}^2 - S$ is closed.

We see that:
$$ \bar{A} = \{ (x,y) \mid x \geq y \}$$

We prove that $\bar{A}$ is closed by showing that it contains all its cluster points. If $\mathbf{a} = (x,y)$ is a cluster point of $\bar{A}$, then it is the limit of a convergent sequence of points $\mathbf{x}_n = (x_n,y_n)$ in $\bar{A}$. So we have that:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbf{x}_n &= \mathbf{a} \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n,y_n) &= (x,y) \\
\end{align*}
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x \qquad\qquad \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = y $$
We note that, since all the points $\mathbf{x}_n$ are in $\bar{S}$:
\begin{align*}
x_n &\geq y_n  & \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \\
x_n - y_n &\geq 0  & \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ x_n - y_n \right] &\geq 0 \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n - \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n &\geq 0 \\
x - y &\geq 0 \\
x &\geq y
\end{align*}
Therefore, any cluster point $\mathbf{a} = (x,y)$ of the set $\bar{A}$ is also in $\bar{A}$.

Since $\bar{A}$ contains all its cluster points, it is closed.

Therefore, $A$ is open.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $f: R^2 \to R:  (x,y) \mapsto x - y$. Thus $A = f^{-1}((-\infty,0))$. $A$ is the pre-image of an open set, hence open under a continuous map.